# find ip address using hostname

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two linux servers and i'm trying to access them remotely. I know the ip of the first server but i forgot the ip of the other one.

I'm trying to use nslookup, I did

```
nslookup server2
```

and the output was:

```
Server:         192.168.2.1
Address:        192.168.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   server2
Address: 90.222.143.15
```

and then i tried to use it again but with server1 and I got the same output...

Anyway, why is the output the same for both server? is nslookup the better option to find out the ip of the other linux server that i have? What other option can I use?

Comment: What protocol are you using to access the remote server..all common protocols allow both hostname and IP addresses to access them..also `server1`, `server2` are not FQDN and the response is coming from `192.168.2.1`..use `nslookup server2.whatever.com 8.8.8.8` to check from Google's DNS, replace `whatever.com` with the actual domain name..

Comment: how can i know what the domain name is?

Comment: does server1 and server2 have the same doman name ? if so use `nslookup IP_of_server1 8.8.8.8` and you should get the domain name if it has one entered..

Comment: i only got this output 
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 69.30.1.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Comment: that means it is not configured in the zone file..by the way it seems you have run `nslookup 69.30.1.10 8.8.8.8` that means the IP of server1 is `69.30.1.10` and hence the IP of server2 should be `90.222.143.15` ..right ?

Comment: To facilitate accessing servers, domain names are usually assigned and added to appropriate domain zones. Sure, you can access some servers by IP as well, but you have to remember their IPs then and embed them into links/commands. It is a responsibility of a box’s administrator to know its IP and conduct all related maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ping instead:

```
$ ping server2
```

nslookup and ping use different techniques for name resolution.

An in-depth explanation for this can be found here:
http://cbfive.com/ping-vs-nslookup/

Comment: i also tried that but its taking too long to ping